# how to get the array data into foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

how to get the array data into foreach loop in php

am having the code as follows

```
 $years = $this->report_model->get_year();
            print_r($years);
```

when am printing am getting as

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1972-1973 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1973-1974 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1974-1975 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1975-1976 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1976-1977 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1977-1978 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [financial_year] => 1978-1979 )
```

when i was giving in foreach loop as

```
            foreach ($years as $year) {
            $data['result_data'][] = $this->report_model->get_historical_data($year);
        }
```

am getting php error as

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 42
```

what was the mistake am doing here

Comment: Are you using a framework or third party library of some sort? How is data access configured?

Answer (score 1):

Change this `$this->report_model->get_historical_data($year);`

To this

`$this->report_model->get_historical_data($year->financial_year);`

Comment: hi am having code as if ((count($years) >= 1) && $filter) {
   foreach ($years as $year) {
    $data['result_data'][] = $this->report_model->get_historical_data($year);
   }
   //print_r($data);
  }
  else {
   foreach ($years as $year) {
    $data['result_data'][] = $this->report_model->get_historical_data($year->financial_year);
   }
   //print_r($data);
  }
  
foreach ($data['result_data'] as $key => $getValue){
echo $getValue[0][0]->state;
} but am getting php error

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered  Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Instead of `$getValue[0][0]->state;` use `$getValue->state;`

Comment: also you can use `var_dump()` function to debug variables. For example make `var_dump($getValue)` inside foreach loop. End give me the result

Comment: am getting an array of values with specifying array(50) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#174 (1) { ["state"]=> string(7) "Alabama" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#175 (1) { ["state"]=> string(7) "Alaska*" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#176 (1) { ["state"]=> string(7) "Arizona" }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($years as $year) {
            $data['result_data'][] = $this->report_model->get_historical_data($year->financial_year);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the collection is part of the array

Try something like this:

```
foreach (array $years as $key => $object) { 
     echo $object->financial_year;
}
```